# Binding to usercontrol dependencyproperty not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have usercontrol that has only one textblock inside it. I have custom dependency property to set the text of the textblock. However I have some problems at getting binding working.

Here's the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpf2.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestProperty}"></TextBlock>
</UserControl>

public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestPropertyTestDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl));

    public string TestProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestPropertyTestDependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestPropertyTestDependencyProperty, value); }
    }

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:TestControl TestProperty="TestString"/> <!-- Works -->
        <local:TestControl TestProperty="{Binding TestValue}"/><!-- Does not work -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue}"/> <!-- Works -->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string TestValue { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        TestValue = "TestString";
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As the comments say, setting TestProperty="TestString" works, but if I try to do a binding it won't work even though the same binding works for TextBlock.

Here's the binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TestValue' property not found on 'object' ''TestControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=TestValue; DataItem='TestControl' (Name=''); target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'TestProperty' (type 'String')
```

Setting name to mainwindow and then binding like this:

```
<local:TestControl TestProperty="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName, Path=TestValue}"/>
```

Works, but why would I need ElementName, when the binding for TextBlock does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UserControl` you programmatically set its `DataContext` property to the `UserControl` itself. So when you use your UserControl inside a Window, it cannot inherit the Window's `DataContext`.
Your Usercontrol has no `TestValue` property, so you obtain a bining error message.

The simpiest solution is to remove the DataContext setting from your UserControl and then change the binding in the `TextBlock`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpf2.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</UserControl>
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Doesn't work since "Self" is the TextBlock, but thanks anyway. {Binding ElementName=UserControlName, Path=TestProperty} worked after I removed the datacontext line from usercontrol.

Comment: It should of course be `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`. As a general rule, *never* set a UserControl's DataContext to itself, as that will effectively prevent inheriting an "external" DataContext from the UserControl's Parent.

Comment: You are both right, I made a mistake. The point it that you cannot set the DataContext of your UserControl.